# Spectre.css - Break flexbox to another row instead of shrinking?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox, spectre.css

I'm new to coding and tried to build a small responsive website with [Spectre.css](https://picturepan2.github.io/spectre/index.html).

I want 3 [cards](https://picturepan2.github.io/spectre/components/cards.html) in a row and if the viewport gets too small, they should go in the next row.
Currently they just shrink but don't go in the next row.

Spectre.css provides media queries but I'm not sure how to actually use the provided structure...
See [Flexbox Grid](https://picturepan2.github.io/spectre/layout/grid.html) and [Responsive](https://picturepan2.github.io/spectre/layout/responsive.html)

Tried to figure it out myself but... mhhh :D

```
<div class="container grid-xl">
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="card column col-3"></div>
        <div class="card column col-3"></div>
        <div class="card column col-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try setting the flex items to `flex-shrink: 0`. This disables the shrinking feature. The default setting is normally `flex-shrink: 1` (as defined in the spec).

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer myself.

Instead of adding only `col-3` I had to add more than one argument.
Like `col-3 col-3 col-md-5 col-sm-11` to make the line breaks.

Sounds logic...

Now it works as intended.